# Null check in if conditions

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have this code in Java

```
return mFingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints() &&
       createKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, true) &&
       initCipher(mCipher, DEFAULT_KEY_NAME);
```

which I have converted to Kotlin as shown here

```
return mFingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints() &&
        createKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, true) &&
        if (mCipher != null) {
            mCipher?.apply { initCipher(this, DEFAULT_KEY_NAME) }
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
```

Is there a better way to write the Kotlin code so it is more concise? Variable mCipher is defined as

```
private var mCipher: Cipher? = null
```

at the class level.

Comment: Why doesn't the Java code work in Kotlin as is? Does `initCipher` not return a `Boolean`?

Comment: The problem is that Kotlin complains that mCipher may have changed between the null check and the access in initCipher.

Comment: It would be nice to see the signature of `initCipher`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?.` on a nullable receiver returns the result of the function if the receiver is not null, and null otherwise.

Combining this with `.apply` we can write:

[..] `&& mCipher?.apply { initCipher(this, DEFAULT_KEY_NAME) } != null`

Comment: Cool, thanks - I missed that I could make use of the return of apply.

Comment: It's better to use `let` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, why can't you copy-paste the Java code to Kotlin? It will work as-is:

```
return mFingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()
       && createKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, true)
       && initCipher(mCipher, DEFAULT_KEY_NAME)
```

If `initCipher(...)` can handle `null` as its parameter, then you don't need to check `mCipher` before passing it to the method.

**Update:**

It seems that you've converted  `initCipher` from Java to Kotlin, and now it can't accept `null` as its argument. Then, assuming you don't have a concurrent access to `mCipher`, add a null-assertion `!!` to the code:

```
return mFingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()
       && createKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, true)
       && initCipher(mCipher!!, DEFAULT_KEY_NAME)
```